# How do to make edits on a webpage that change display on another webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create two webpages. One that works as a customization page where I can upload images to the customize page and they display on the display page, and where I can type input on the customization page and it will display in a specific area on the display page. Can this be done via css and html and if so how would I go about this.

This is the code I currently have to display upload and display images, but it only uploads to the custom page so how would I connect the two so when I upload an image it uploads to the display page as well.

Images code Javascript:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', function() {
      if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
          var img = document.querySelector('img');  // $('img')[0]
          img.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]); // set src to blob url
          img.onload = imageIsLoaded;
      }
  });
});

function imageIsLoaded() { 
  alert(this.src);  // blob url
  // update width and height ...
}
```

Image code HTML:

```
<input type='file' />
<br><img id="myImg" src="#" alt="your image" height=200 width=100>
```

This is the code I currently have to display text, but it only uploads to the custom page so how would I connect the two so when I upload an image it uploads to the display page as well. Thanks!

Text code Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".preview").on('keyup', function() {
    $($(this).data('copy')).html($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Text code HTML:

```
<div class="field">
  <label class="paddingleft" for="fullname">Full Name</label>
  <div class="center">
    <input type="text" class="biginputbarinline preview" id="ShipToFullname" data-copy="#name" name="ShipToFullname" required>
  </div>
</div>

<br>

Your name is:
<div id="name"></div>
```

A simpler method I also used:

```
 <input onkeyup="$('#name').html(this.value)" ... />
 <p id='name'></p>
```

Comment: you need a server side script to save your customization and upload image , else , you can use a popup and fill that one up from the current page, nothing will be saved.. it will be lost once the popup closed

Comment: Technically you could do it with the Storage API, or IndexedDb, or using SPA technologies (i.e., store the values in memory and don't actually change HTML pages, just make it look like you did). But all of that is a bit broader than can be answered in a single question. I encourage you to do some research in "single page applications" and how they work, assuming you don't want the customizations to be permanent.

Comment: Is it only a frontend project with no server-side support? Are you using any specific framework or normal javascript? Is your goal only to upload images and input text and show them on the other page? I need your answer to post the solution.

Comment: @MajedBadawi Yes, it is only frontend and no server side at the moment. And yes I am using javascript for clocks that I have present on the webpage. But my only goal is to upload images into a spot on the display page until another is uploaded and the same goes for text that I want in a specific position

Comment: @MajedBadawi Could you also upload it for doing text. I tried but was unable to mimic the method you did for image correctly. And also if I wanted to duplicate the image function so that when the file is uploaded I could display it in two area how I would do that? Thanks again for your time and help

Comment: When do you mean by "two area"?

Comment: @MajedBadawi Pretty much I am using a position command to position the images on the display page. I want the same image displayed twice in 2 different places on the page, and was wondering how would this be possible. I just need it uploaded twice and from there I can position it myself and edit the size.

Comment: @StackGuru code updated.

Comment: @MajedBadawi You are a God Send! Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the values on the first page:

```
<body>
     <input type='file' />
     <br><img id="myImg" src="#" alt="your image" height=200 width=100>
     <input type='text' id="text" placeholder="Enter text"/>
     <button id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
</body>
<script>
     window.addEventListener('load', function() {
          document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', function() {
               if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    var baseString;
                    reader.onloadend = function () {
                         baseString = reader.result;
                         console.log(baseString); 
                         localStorage.setItem('image',baseString)
                         document.getElementById("myImg").setAttribute('src',localStorage.getItem("image"));
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
               }
          });
          document.getElementById('submitBtn').addEventListener('click', function(){
               var text = document.getElementById('text').value;
               console.log(text)
               if(!text)
                    alert("Please enter input");
               else
                    localStorage.setItem('text',text);
          });
     });
</script>
```

And to retrieve it in the other page:

```
<body>
     <img src="" id="image"/>
     <img src="" id="image1"/>
     <p id="text"></p>
</body>
<script>
     window.onload = function(){
               if(localStorage.getItem("image")){
                    document.getElementById("image").setAttribute('src',localStorage.getItem("image"));
                    document.getElementById("image1").setAttribute('src',localStorage.getItem("image"));
               }
               if(localStorage.getItem("text"))
                    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("text");
     }
</script>
```

Note that this is not the optimal solution as there are better techniques using a modern framework, however, this will serve you purpose given the technologies you are using.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I wanted. Im tinkering with it now. If I have any questions I will let you know. Thanks again!